# About contraception pills efficacy

Tags: obstetrics, sex, health-education

It is supposed to take "placebo pills" when a woman is on her menstruation and just only the first time she start taking contraception pills is mandatory to consume a pill on the first day of the period, vice she was always taking 21 pills, the new period started and she consumed the first pill of the new box every month, when it is advisable to take a rest or utilize the placebo pills (the seven other pills).

What could happen if the girl is taking contraception pills during her period time? Would the efficacy of them be diminished?

Comment: Hello, I've changed it. Hope it is correct now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The point of the sugar pills is to induce a withdrawal bleed, but that may not be necessary. Efficiency is not affected.

> Do I have to bleed every month?
>
> There is no evidence that shows women need monthly withdrawal bleeding, and no health problems are linked to skipping or eliminating bleeding. Studies have found that using the pill continuously for two or more cycles before having withdrawal bleeding is as safe and effective at preventing pregnancy as a traditional regimen.4

http://www.arhp.org/Publications-and-Resources/Patient-Resources/fact-sheets/Understanding-Menstrual